# Understanding the significance of LeNet-5 w/ MNIST data set

Tags: neural-network, keras, image-classification, mnist, convolutional-neural-network

I'm beginning to learn about conv nets and started with what I understand to be one of the seminal works: LeNet-5. However, my limited experimentation doesn't seem to show any advantage over a single hidden layer fully-connected network. I'd like to understand what's going on.

For reference, the LeNet-5 paper is here: http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/publis/pdf/lecun-01a.pdf

**The Fully-Connected Network**

The MNIST data set has 60k training examples of 28x28 pixels each, and 10k in the test (validation) set. My fully-connected network has this topology:

Layer 0 (input): 28*28 = 784 inputs
Layer 1 (hidden): 100 units (ReLU and sigmoid activation were tested)
Layer 2 (output): 10 units (softmax)

Cross-entropy loss was used and stochastic gradient descent with a batch size of 64 and 10,000 iterations was used for training using custom code I wrote myself.

**LeNet-5**

I used the LeNet-5 example [here](https://github.com/TaavishThaman/LeNet-5-with-Keras/blob/master/lenet_5.py). It's not identical to the original network in that it uses ReLU activations, max pooling instead of average pooling, and has more connections than the original implementation in layer 3 (that is, layer 3 is a dense layer, which was **not** the case in LeNet-5 but I haven't been able to find a 100% faithful implementation using modern frameworks like Keras).

Nevertheless, I would expect it to exhibit some of the characteristics cited in the paper, namely these two metrics:

- Significantly lower error (less than 1% cited in the paper, vs. ~4-5% for fully-connected case)
- Tolerance of translational offsets in the images of up to 50% of the character height.

My results don't match this at all. See table below. LeNet-5 takes a 32x32 input image (formed by padding the 28x28 image), and I've applied various rotations (degrees) and translations (pixels). At a vertical shift of 5px, LeNet-5 fails pretty badly, contrary to the paper's claim that it can still identify characters.

[image: Comparison of LeNet-5 to fully-connected network]

**Questions**

1. What am I missing? Is the Keras implementation (which I did not write) flawed?
2. What are the advantages of LeNet-5 given these results?
3. What further experiments can I conduct to convince myself of its advantages?

Thank you :)